# Подключение скрипта js к Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

Как подключить скрипт js к джумле?

Answer (score 1):

А разве joomla не имеет html разметки ? подключение такое же как и везде, находите index.php, открываете редактором (например блокнотом), и вставляйте что хотите  и куда хотите. Удачи